# Show/hide children on parent click

Tags: jquery

I want child show/hide when click on parent

**HTML**

```
<div id="a" class="childshow">Parent
       <div id="b" class="childshow" style="display:none">Child
           <div id="c" class="childshow" style="display:none">inner child
          </div>
          <div id="c1" class="childshow" style="display:none">inner child1
          </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".childshow").click(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).find('>.childshow').css("display")=="none"){
        $(this).find('>.childshow').show();
    }else{
        $(this).find('>.childshow').hide();
    }   
});
```

but this does not work correctly

Comment: post your related HTML codes to

Comment: Include your html. Also why are you randomly using a `jQuery` when you're selecting everything else with `$`?

Comment: i post html but not showing

Comment: Give outermost Class Different name say parentClass first.

Comment: What is current problem with you

Comment: i want when when i click on parent its child show and when i again click on parent its child hide if childs shows

Answer (score 7):

You could use `toggle()` instead and stop event from bubbling and BTW you should use `.children()`:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cMJeQ/1/)

```
$(".childshow").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    jQuery(this).children('.childshow').toggle();
});
```

Comment: +1 for using `toggle()`....:).. i posted with `show()`, `hide()`.. didn't think of `toggle()` then.

Answer (score 3):

here you go

```
 $(".childshow").click(function (e) {
     e.stopPropagation(); //to stop event bubbling
     if ($(this).children('.childshow').is(':visible')) { //check if hidden or not
         $(this).children('.childshow').hide(); //if yes hide

     } else {

         $(this).children('.childshow').show(); // else show
     }
 });
```

or use `toggle()` instead of `show` and `hide`

```
$(".childshow").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children('.childshow').toggle();
 });
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/hg8jm/)